# htaccess with one fixed parameter not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a URL with 1 fixed parameter.

- `localhost/login`
- `localhost/signup`

to

- `localhost/account.php?action=log`
- `localhost/account.php?action=reg`

it worked fine with this

```
RewriteRule ^login$ account.php?action=log [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^signup$ account.php?action=reg [NC,L]
```

but when I added Google oauth
it returns a URL like this

`localhost/login?code=.....`

so I changed it to

```
RewriteRule ^login?(.*)$ account.php?action=log&code=$1 [NC,L]
```

but I couldn't get the code variable with `$_GET['code']`
and `var_dump($_GET)` returns
`array(2) { ["action"]=> string(3) "log" ["code"]=> string(0) "" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only, you can not check the query string with that, that would need a RewriteCond.

But you should not *need* anything in addition to the already existing `^login$` redirect - just add the [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag, so that the original query string gets merged with your existing one.

```
RewriteRule ^login$ account.php?action=log [QSA,NC,L]
```